# How this code block avoiding hard-coding. Elements Of Programming Interviews Question 5.1

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitmask, hardcode

I recently started preparing for job interviews and came across with this example question which ask us to find how many bits are set to 1 in a number and answer code block.

> The Following program tests bits one at a time starting with the least
> significant bit. It illustrates shifting and **masking**; **it also shows
> how to avoid hard-coding the size of the integer word**

```
public static short countBits(int x){

        short numBits = 0;
        while (x != 0){
            numBits += (x & 1);
            x = x >>> 1;
        }
        return numBits;
    }
```

What I do not understand here is how this ***code*** avoiding **hard-coding**. The wikipedia article says about hard coding;

> **Hard coding is the software development practice of embedding data
> directly into the source code of a program or other executable object,
> as opposed to obtaining the data from external sources or generating
> it at runtime.**

In this article it says we are hard-coding if we are taking data directly from source code. Which is exactly what we are doing in the method. We are taking the data from source code:

Parameter → `int x` is hard coded.

The second part I do not understand is how we are not hard coded `size of the integer word`.
What is that mean?

Comment: Does an integer have 16, 32 or 64 bits? The code does not care about it because the size of an integer is not hard coded.

Comment: How can we hard code the size of the integer then? Is it the most usual way the book has done?

Comment: `for (int bit = 0; bit < 32; bit++) { ... }` would hardcode ints having 32 bits.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Then can we say that there are languages int size differs? In Java it is always 4 bytes or 32 bits? So this code created for avoiding the difficulties on the other languages?

Comment: Yes, different languages *could* have different int sizes, they might change depending on the version / platform. In java they are fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing `x&1+(x>>>1)&1+(x>>>2)&1+...(x>>>63)&1` or `for(int i=0; i<64; i++) { ... }`. These both would assume that integers have 64 bits *(which btw would take unnecessarily more time as integers only use 32 bits in java, but that's the reason you want to avoid hard-coding)*. Your method doesn't care how many bits an integer has, it just cares that there are still 1's somewhere in it.